# How to connect a physical device to a particular virtual network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, esxi

I'm trying to emulate a small network with 4 interconnected computers in VMWare ESXI server and accessing via vSphere. 3 of them are windows based computers with their own console and I managed to set them up and interconnect them via a virtual network. However, the 4th one is a vx works based real time system and I cannot emulate this on the VMWare running on a windows host. Hence I decided to use a real physical device for that.

However, in the physical set-up, this device boots via network by broadcasting an ethernet boot request and one of the other computer(say the first one) sends the response, assigns an IP to this device and later the device boots from that system. There is no console for this device for me to assign an IP to it. Now, my problem is that how do I connect this device to the virtual system?

One possibility is that I could connect this device to my organizational LAN directly. But, then there is no guarantee that the network boot request would be answered only by the first virtual machine above. Can I somehow restrict the network broadcast to a given virtual network? Are there any other ways to achieve this?